# Is it necessary to have a mobile friendly design for html sitemap?

Tags: usability, website-design, user-behavior, mobile-web, seo

We have really long Sitemap for our desktop version, As an adaptive design, we had created a separate sitemap for Mobile site which has very limited links but the client wants everything that's there in the Desktop version. Is there any way to show all the links on Mobile site? or Just show Desktop version for Mobile also?

Answer (score 2):

With no screenshot it is hard to tell if the desktop version will also work on mobile. But I guess it’s just a bunch of links at the bottom of each page.

For mobile you can place them vertically at the bottom but that will take a long way to scroll. Otherwise, and [only if done the right way](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/support-mobile-navigation/), you can put them in a hamburger menu.

Comment: Hi @jazZRo I was referring to the Sitemap page, here's the URL: http://www.gizbot.com/sitemap/ Open it on Desktop and Mobile(In Mobile w e have limited links but we want to add everything that's there on the Desktop. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: As long as everything on the sitemap can normally be found through the main navigation, there is nothing wrong with the designs for mobile and desktop. One tip: Show the search bar above the sitemap instead of hiding it behind the click of a button.